# In Postgres SQL how can I use group by and ignore if any row in grouping is null?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table with data like this

```
id group order value
-------------------------
1  1     1     23
2  1     2     34
3  2     1     234
4  2     2     77
5  2     3     102
6  3     1     78
7  3     2     NULL
```

I want to insert into table so I have one row per group, with the value showing a string of comma-separated values orders based on the order. **But I want it ignore any groups that contain a null value.**

So the result I want is this

```
id group value
----------------
1  1     23,34
2  2     234,77,102
```

But with

```
SELECT
row_number() over () as id,
group,
string_agg(t1.value, ',' ORDER BY "ORDER"),
FROM  t2
GROUP BY group
```

I currently have

```
id group value
----------------
1  1     23,34
2  2     234,77,102
3  3     78
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT row_number() over () as id, group,
       string_agg(t1.value, ',' ORDER BY "ORDER"),
FROM t2
GROUP BY group
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(t1.value);
```

Comment: Thanks, thats it, my SQL is a bit rusty